# C#: How to send text like label or textbox value from form to crystal reports in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have a form having datagridview and other labels like name, amount etc. I can successfully send datagridview data to crystal reports but i dont know how to send the label or textbox values to crystal reports and how to show it in crystal reports? is anyone have any idea about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by sending html format into the crystal report, not direct label or textboxes. Crystal report understand the html partially(check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791321/what-html-tags-are-supported-in-crystal-reports-2008) for partially means)

Check this links for sending html to crystal report.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1209306.aspx?Possible+to+display+HTML+with+Crystal+Reports+

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3196185

[Crystal report with HTML content formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024273/crystal-report-with-html-content-formatting)